# Multiple GitHub Sessions Open With R Studio

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

Every time I open R Studio, GitHub will also open--only it will open 3 sessions/windows. Within R Studio, when I change project options for a project tied to Git Version Control, the same thing happens. I can have 9 instances of the GitHub application open on my computer screen at the same time. Inevitably, some of them stop working/crash. Not sure how to stop this. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. Please let me know if I can provide further details.

Comment: Please refer this to the RStudio support forum.